# [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication

Using the following code to Authenticate to Firebase using appleId:
[AuthenticationViewModel.swift](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-video-samples/blob/911b88756a174f36e573be5bad83d9f0dd430234/fundamentals/apple/firestore/final/Favourites/Shared/Auth/AuthenticationViewModel.swift#L39)

Getting the following error:

```
10.19.1 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: Error Domain=com.google.app_check_core Code=4 "The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.}
Error authenticating: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
```

Sometimes it work, some times it doesn't.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Are you running this on the simulator? If so, you need to use the debug provider : https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider